# Protractor configuration error w/ TypeScript + Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, protractor, webpack

I'm having problems getting Protractor to run in my project. It's having problems with my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "components": ["app/components"],
      "core": ["app/core"],
      "data": ["app/data"],
      "pages": ["app/pages"],
      "schemas": ["app/schemas"],
      "utility": ["app/utility"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

It's specifically failing on "baseUrl" and "paths" options. If I take those out, it runs perfectly. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I'm currently using Protractor 3.2.2 and we updated to 4.0 just to get this stack trace:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
Unknown compiler option 'baseUrl'. (5023)
Unknown compiler option 'paths'. (5023)
    at Object.register (/Users/Dan/git/LifeSiteAngular2/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:185:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Dan/git/LifeSiteAngular2/node_modules/ts-node/register.js:1:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Dan/git/LifeSiteAngular2/config/protractor.conf.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
```

Comment: You are confusing the protractor config with the tsconfig. Protractor config file should have an absolute URL for the browser to hit, but the tsconfig baseUrl/paths are for module resolutions https://gist.github.com/vladima/725949fd9464e6a94771#pathMappings

Comment: The first comment is your answer. I don't know why it's not posted as the answer.

Comment: What do you mean? He was talking about the protractor configuration's "baseUrl", not tsconfig's "baseUrl" and "paths" options.

Comment: tsconfig does does not have an option for "baseUrl" and "paths." Those are protractor configuration options. That is why your TypeScript compiler is failing to compile. And that is what the first comment was explaining.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039

Comment: Gotcha, I take my last comment back. However, that's a TypeScript 2 feature, no? Are you using TypeScript 2 compiler?

Comment: Yeh for some reason this was working in 1.8.10 when compiling .ts files using webpack, so updating to 2.0 fixed this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is an older version of typescript not being compatible with the baseUrl and paths options inside tsconfig.json.

This is fixed by updating protractor to version 4.0.0, and typescript to version 2.0.0.